# array_sum in python

Tags: python

Is there any function similar to PHP [array_sum](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp) function ?

I mean I have an object, for an instance:

```
obj = {}

obj['t'] = 2
obj['x'] = 4
obj['z'] = 6
```

and I would like to sum it without any loop, by one function.

Comment: You want to achieve it within your Django template or in python code (views, models, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreword: Note that non-integer indexed arrays as in PHP are known to as **dictionaries** in Python.

You can take your sum using the builtin `sum` function:

```
sum(obj.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sum(obj.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of a dictionary's values as follows:

```
sum(obj.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `obj` is a dictionary this will work:

```
sum(obj.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can sum value of dictionary by using,

```
sum(obj.values())
```

and for Python < 2.7, You may use `itervalues` instead like,

```
sum(obj.itervalues())
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sum(obj.values())
```

to get sum of values